# Global dependency as an argument to each handler

Tags: python, fastapi

Looking at the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/#settings-in-a-dependency) I got to use my app settings in this way:

```
import config

...

@router.post('')
async def my_handler(
    ...
    settings: config.SettingsCommon = fastapi.Depends(config.get_settings),
):
    ...
```

But I am not satisfied with repeating everywhere `import config`, `config.get_settings`.

Is there a way to use `settings` in my handlers without repeating myself?

> Because **FastAPI** cares about helping you minimize code repetition.

Comment: Doesn't the variant of the global config object in the module suit instead of the dependency in each handler?

Comment: This is what I am doing right now. However, doing it through dependencies is more canonical, I think. It allows to inject a different dependency. It may postpone the settings creation to the function call, instead of doing it during module import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to inject global dependencies. You can still declare them and the code inside the dependencies will run as normal.

[Docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/global-dependencies/) on global dependencies for reference.

Without any external dependency, I can think of three ways of using global dependencies. You can set a private variable with your dependency and get that dependency using a function.

You can also use the same approach without a global private variable, but instead using a cache decorator (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache)).

Finally, you can implement the singleton pattern if using a class as a dependency.

Something like:

```py
class Animal:
    _singleton = None

    @classmethod
    def singleton(cls) -> "Animal":
        if cls._singleton is None:
            cls._singleton = Animal()
        return cls._singleton
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Class Based Views](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/class-based-views/) from the fastapi_utils package.

As an example:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv
from starlette import requests
from logging import Logger

import config
from auth import my_auth

router = APIRouter(
    tags=['Settings test'],
    dependencies=[Depends(my_auth)]  # injected into each query, but my_auth return values are ignored, throw Exceptions
)


@cbv(router)
class MyQueryCBV:
    settings: config.SettingsCommon = Depends(config.get_settings)  # you can get settings here

    def __init__(self, r: requests.Request):  # called for each query, after their dependencies have been evaluated
        self.logger: Logger = self.settings.logger
        self.logger.warning(str(r.headers))

    @router.get("/cbv/{test}")
    def test_cbv(self, test: str):
        self.logger.warning(f"test_cbv: {test}")
        return "test_cbv"

    @router.get("/cbv2")
    def test_cbv2(self):
        self.logger.warning(f"test_cbv2")
        return "test_cbv2"
```