# how to handle database connection when using APIRouter in fastapi

Tags: python, pymongo, fastapi

I am trying to understand how to properly split bigger application into multiple files.
But I am facing Database related issue when I try to do CRUD operation from a different file than the main

**In Main.py I have made the connection to the mongodb like this:**

```
app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(admin_routes.router)

@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_db_client():
    app.mongodb_client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    app.database = app.mongodb_client["db"]
    app.Admin = app.database["Admin"] 
    print("Connected to the MongoDB database!",app.database)
```

**and in my admin_routes.py**

```
@router.post("/CreateAdmin" , tags=["Admin"])
async def create_admin(data: signup_admin): 
    if router.Admin.count_documents({'phone':  data.phone }) : 
        return {"message": "Phone Already Exist !"}
    elif router.Admin.count_documents({'username':  data.username }) : 
        return {"message": "Username Already Exist !"}
    else: 
        mydict = { "phone":data.phone,"username":data.username,"password":data.password }
        x = router.Admin.insert_one(mydict)  
        return{"status":"ok","message":"Admin Account Created!"}
```

But I am getting error `AttributeError: 'APIRouter' object has no attribute 'Admin'` when the I access the endpoint CreateAdmin

Whats the proper way to handle the connection so that database operations are available from the routers ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're attaching`mongodb_client` to the `FastAPI` instance? I would recommend putting them as global objects (if need be, in a separate python file to avoid circular imports).

Comment: maybe check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191870/global-dependency-as-an-argument-to-each-handler/74306790#74306790) answer

Comment: it won't solve your error, but it's a way of doing what you want

Comment: yep it was a stupid mistake on my part , making the connection in a separate db file was the right way to go about it